# Truncation of website with Jsoup and Android Studio

Tags: java, android, dom, android-studio, jsoup

I am using Jsoup library to extract data from this site:
[Tom's hardware benchmarks](http://www.tomshardware.com/charts/cpu-charts-2015/-01-CinebenchR15,Marque_fbrandx14,3693.html)

I use this code for connect to the site and extract data:

```
  protected Void doInBackground(Object[] params) {
    doc = Jsoup.connect(url).maxBodySize(Integer.MAX_VALUE).header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip").userAgent("Dalvik").method(Connection.Method.GET).timeout(Integer.MAX_VALUE).get();


    try {

    if (doc != null) {

                    css_text = doc.select("div[class=clLeft] label[for]");

                    for (int i = 0; i < css_text.size(); i++)
                        elem1[i] = css_text.eq(i).text();

                    css_text = doc.select("ul[style=margin-left:0px;] span");

                    css_score = doc.select("div[class=clRight clearfix]");


                    for (int j = 0; j < css_text.size(); j++) {
                        elem2[j] = css_text.eq(j).text();
                        score[j] = css_score.eq(j).text();

                        processori_score_arraylist.add(elem1[j] + "\n" + elem2[j] + "   " + score[j]);


                        }

                    }


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                return null;


            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

                processori_score_listview.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        }

    }
```

I read that there is a default limitation of 1MB, and that can truncate the webpage. This webpage instead don't appear to 1MB so I use first a value by me but don't work always. For a problem that I don't understand, when i am in debug mode and see the variable *doc* as **Document**, the webpage is download all sometime and other sometimes not. I don't understand why.
Then I try to change the value of *maxBodySize* to **0** and then to **Integer.MAX_VALUE** and also *timeout* value reading other post and search of Internet but it doesn't resolve the problem.
Anybody can suggest me cause or solution of the problem?
I hope that is clear what the problem is, if not I am available for doubts.

Other post of this problem that I found:

[jsoup don't get full data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29656765/jsoup-dont-get-full-data/29713698#29713698)

[JSOUP not downloading complete html if the webpage is big in size. Any alternatives to this or any workarounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28083119/jsoup-not-downloading-complete-html-if-the-webpage-is-big-in-size-any-alternati)

**Here the HTML page how is truncated**:

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
     <head> 
      <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"> 
      <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0"> 
      <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"> 
      <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"> 
      <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT"> 
      <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"> 
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=/distil_r_captcha.html?Ref=/charts/cpu-charts-2015/-01-CinebenchR15,Marque_fbrandx14,3693.html&amp;distil_RID=1CB642F0-76B5-11E5-9B22-93799C16BE3F&amp;distil_TID=20151019225954"> 
      <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(window){
            try {
                if (typeof sessionStorage !== 'undefined'){
                    sessionStorage.setItem('distil_referrer', document.referrer);
                }
            } catch (e){}
        })(window);
    </script> 
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/destilar-fbxcdbtcwcebrsxtw.js" defer></script>
      <style type="text/css">#d__fFH{position:absolute;top:-5000px;left:-5000px}#d__fF{font-family:serif;font-size:200px;visibility:hidden}#ssxfwzexyqctzdfy{display:none!important}</style>
     </head> 
     <body> 
      <div id="distil_ident_block">
       &nbsp;
      </div>   
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some reasons I see:

#### 1) Code readiness

Don't forget to clean your code. It looks like quite messy from your question. The strange behavior may live there.

#### 2) Random downtime

The code may hit some random downtime from the server. In your case, I would strengthen the error management.

```
Document doc=null;

try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect(url) //
           .timeout(0) // Relax the server by according it infinite time...
           .maxBodySize(0) // We don't know the size of the server response...
           .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip") //
           .userAgent("Dalvik") //
           .get();

    // * Extract data from doc
    // If something is missing, raise an exception
    // or write a code that can accomodate with the missing data

} catch(Throwable t) {
   // Using Throwable may seem extreme here, however you'll quickly see what's going on

   // Carefully log what happened
   log.error("Something BAD happened...", t);

   // Ultimately, if something is present in the document, dump it for later investigation
   if (doc!=null) {
      dump(doc.outerHtml());
   }
}
```

#### 3) Website protection

Some website have clever anti-webscraping protection. So when you fetch urls, do it slowly. The code should mark a random pause between 3000 to 5000 milliseconds on each fetch. It looks like more human. You can also use some proxy for changing your ip adress.